# Concatenate URL with variable in C#

Tags: c#, url, httprequest, uri

I am trying to concatenate a URL with a variable and then the "rest" of the URL.

It goes like this:

```
variableName = "1234";

....

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _configuration["MY_BASE_URL" + variableName + "/theRestOfTheUrl"]);
```

Where the "MY_BASE_URL" is saved as an variable as: `"http://mytestsite.com/users/"`

but when doing this I get the error:

> "error":"An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

**What am I doing wrong?** When just passing:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _configuration["MY_BASE_URL"]);
```

where I instead have named "MY_BASE_URL" as "http://mytestsite.com/users/1234/theRestOfTheUrl" I get no errors, but I would to be able to add the variableName too + what comes after, with the option of having the variableName being dynamic - and therefore I can't give it as an entire hardcoded string.

Comment: Create a variable and try to create `MY_BASE_URL" + variableName + "/theRestOfTheUrl` out of `_configuration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_configuration["MY_BASE_URL"]` is a configuration variable which returns your base URL i.e `http://mytestsite.com/users/`, now you need to append variable value to it then hard coded string `/theRestOfTheUrl`.

Instead of writing everything inside `_configuration` key, write it with [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Try

```
string url = $"{_configuration["MY_BASE_URL"]}{variableName}/theRestOfTheUrl";
Console.WriteLine(url); // http://mytestsite.com/users/1234/theRestOfTheUrl
```

Your code will look like

```
variableName = "1234";

....

string url = $"{_configuration["MY_BASE_URL"]}{variableName}/theRestOfTheUrl";
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
```

POC: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWuHNg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed a square bracket `_configuration["MY_BASE_URL"]`

```
variableName = "1234";

....

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _configuration["MY_BASE_URL"] + variableName + "/theRestOfTheUrl");
```